# using one object from Django model class

Tags: python, django

I have two classes:

```
class Works(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    time=models.IntegerField()
    unit= models.ForeignKey(Units)
    price=models.IntegerField()
    approve_need=models.BooleanField()
    person_value= models.IntegerField()
    profession= models.ForeignKey(Professions)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class ProjectsWorks(models.Model):
    project_name= models.ForeignKey(Projects)
    work_name= models.ForeignKey(Works)
    work_amount= models.IntegerField()
    complet_per= models.IntegerField()
    planned_start= models.DateField()
    planned_end= models.DateField()
    fact_start= models.DateField()
    fact_end= models.DateField()
    start_reason= models.CharField(max_length=255)
    end_reason= models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

They both are showed on screen using formsets. After adding data to Works model, Can i somehow do this:
after choosing the

```
work_name= models.ForeignKey(Works)
```

in the formset, the field

```
ProjectWorks.work_amount
```

become equal to the value from

```
Works.time
```

or maybe I can somehow use ForeignKey on specific object?
like

```
class ProjectsWorks(models.Model):
    work_amount= models.ForeignKey(Works.time)
```

Comment: If you want them to be equal, then doesn't this create duplicate data?

Comment: Yes, but anyway, is there a way to access a specific object from class? Like the way classes works, "Class.object"?

Comment: But why can't you just access the time from the linked Works object? ie `my_project.work_amount.time`?